# How to change a content´s workflow state from an url

Tags: 6, emails, nodes, workflows

I have a server installed with apache2 and drupal 6. In my server, users can make some type of new contents. When they make a new content, they receive an e-mail with creation confirmation.

I´d like to add a new funcionality: I´d like that these users could change the new content´s workflow state from this e-mail that they receive and only from this e-mail(In this way, they are required to sign in their e-mail account).

I have thought that this e-mail could include a url which makes these actions, but I don´t know how do it.

Comment: **[On February 24th 2016, Drupal 6 will reach end of life and no longer be supported.](https://www.drupal.org/drupal-6-eol)**

Comment: Thank you very much, I´m going to focus on upgrade my drupal version.